# Split element in string into segments

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, split, nested

I'm trying to split an element of a list within another list where there is whitespace within that element. I have considered using the split() method but I am not sure if it will work for this.

An example of what I am trying to do:

Say I have this list like this:

```
[['H EL LO', 'h el lo'], ['W OR L D', 'w or l d']...]
```

I want to turn it into something like this:

```
[['H', 'EL', 'LO', 'h', 'el', 'lo'], ['W', 'OR', 'L', 'D', 'w', 'or', 'l', 'd']...]
```

where I can iterate over each "segment" (i.e 'H', 'EL', 'LO' etc) and see if they are in another list for the purpose of my overall function. It doesn't have to look exactly like that, but I just need to be able to iterate over the segments. Note that I **don't** want to iterate over **single characters** but rather over the **segments**, so I thought joining the segments together wouldn't be useful.

How would I do this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
data = [['H EL LO', 'h el lo'], ['W OR L D', 'w or l d']]
```

You can use some one-liner magic:

```
print([line.split() for line in [' '.join(group) for group in data]])
```

You could also do something that might be a bit more readable, if you're unfamiliar with Python:

```
temporary_list = []
for group in data:
    new_group = []
    for word in group:
        new_group.extend(word.split())
    temporary_list.append(new_group)
print(temporary_list)
```

Comment: I get an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' when I use that one liner. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I accidentally used the same variable name in both iterations of the for-loops. It worked on my computer, but it is bad practice. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Is there a way to fix that but still utilise list comprehension? Just use a different variable name for the second loop (i.e the second 'd')?

Comment: It definitely splits the segments up via whitespace, but each word is returned twice. E.g. [['H', 'EL', 'LO', 'h', 'el', 'lo'], ['H', 'EL', 'LO', 'h', 'el', 'lo'], ['W', 'OR', 'L', 'D', 'w', 'or', 'l', 'd'], ['W', 'OR', 'L', 'D', 'w', 'or', 'l', 'd']].


And I just like the elegance of one liners that's all, haha. :)

Comment: Also, your edited list comprehension works but it only returns the converted version last list of the original list.

Comment: The output from running the first two lines in my answer is:
[['H', 'EL', 'LO', 'h', 'el', 'lo'], ['W', 'OR', 'L', 'D', 'w', 'or', 'l', 'd']]
It works in both python 2 and python 3.

Comment: I'll fiddle around with the rest of my code and get back to you. Thank you a heap for your help!